# Azure function in maven to access onedrive

Tags: java, spring, maven, azure-functions

I am writing an azure function using java and maven to access onedrive to read content of file when file is uploaded in onedrive.

I am just a beginner in Azure. Have written basic azure function that runs the function on localhost displaying Hello world.

```
@FunctionName("HttpTrigger-Java")
public HttpResponseMessage run(
        @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.FUNCTION) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
        final ExecutionContext context) {
    context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

    // Parse query parameter
    String query = request.getQueryParameters().get("name");
    String name = request.getBody().orElse(query);

    if (name == null) {
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body").build();
    } else {
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("Hello, " + name).build();
    }
}
```

}

I need to write a get request to fetch file from onedrive and display its content. How can I write that code. Most of codes I saw is written in C# or JS. Could anyone help me in writing function that runs in maven.

Comment: Is there specific requirement you are preferring code when there is one drive connector available in Azure Logic Apps.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-onedrive

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-onedriveforbusiness

Comment: Yes it is requirement to write a java code which can be dockerized later.